# Telerik RadPageView as StackView keeps changing title when selected page changes

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I am using WinForms (C#) along with Telerik UI controls.  I have a `RadPageView` that has the `ViewMode` set to `Stack`.  I also have the `ViewElement.StackPosition` set to `Top` and the `ViewElement.ItemSelectionMode` set to `ContentAfterSelected`.

It is a simple section-stack type control that will pop the header of the section to the top of the control when clicked, with the content of that section directly underneath the header.

The issue that I am having is that when I click on one of the sections, and the header goes to the top, this action also changes the big bold header of the parent `RadPageView`, but I do not want it to.  I can change the text of the `RadPageView` by setting the `ViewElement.Header.Text` property on the `RadPageView`, but as soon as I click on one of the sections again it gets set to the section's header.  Essentially, it then just has two headers right in a row that say the exact same thing.

I want to be able to set the header text of the `RadPageView` and not have it change when the selected page changes.

I am fairly new to this whole Telerik thing, so I am sure it is just some simple property, I am just done looking for it at this point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post a sample code replicating your scenario or a small sample app uploaded somewhere, so we can have a look at it?

Comment: Yes, I will certainly do so.  However it may take some time... the project has been shelved for a few days as I was assigned another feature request.  I will get back to you when I come back to the project.  Thanks.